# Compare two variables in PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop2

I had two documents, where I need to filter second document words with  first document words

I had tried but not working

```
lines = LOAD 'abc_doc1.txt';
words = FOREACH lines GENERATE word;
C = GROUP words all;

lines1 = LOAD 'abc_doc2.txt';
words1 = FOREACH lines GENERATE word;
C1 = GROUP words1 all;

D = foreach C1 generate $0 as searchwrd

E= Filter D by (searchwrd!=(foreach C generate $0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of filtering I used join

a. Inner join:

```
A = load '/user/balanagaraju.maliset/Dump/abc.txt'  AS (line:chararray);
B = load '/user/balanagaraju.maliset/Dump/abc.txt' AS (line:chararray); 

words1 = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(line)) as word;
words2 = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(line)) as wordz;

x = JOIN words1 by word , words2 by wordz;

grouped = group x BY word;

D = foreach grouped generate  COUNT(x), group;

Dump D;
```

b.Cross Join:

```
A = load '/user/balanagaraju.maliset/Dump/abc.txt'  AS (line:chararray);
B = load '/user/balanagaraju.maliset/Dump/abc.txt' AS (line:chararray); 

words1 = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(line)) as word;
words2 = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(line)) as word;


C= CROSS words1,words2;
CC = foreach C generate $0 as first ,$1 as second;
R = FILTER CC by first==second;

grouped = group R BY first;

D = foreach grouped generate  group, COUNT(R);

Dump D;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement seems to be :-

You have 2 files A and B. You want exclude all words from file B which are present in file A. You can use left outer join for this.

Script will look like :-

file1 = load 'A' using PigStorage() as (word1:chararray);

file2 = load 'B' using PigStorage() as (word2:chararray);

joined = join file2 by word2 left outer , file1 by word1 ;

filtered = filter joined by word1 is null ;

dump filtered ;

Explanation :- Left outer will make sure to include all words from file2. So all matched words in file1 and file2 will have non-null value. If you filter out NULL value word1 they are the remaining words which are present in file2 but not in file1